# SSL Configuration for java Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, jks

I have my Java Springboot Application with SSL certification and whenever i am trying to run the code its showing me "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [embel] does not identify a key entry" and when i tried accessing it with the "keytool -list -v -keystore amr.p12" its showing me  the right information like below " Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: embel
Creation date: 02-Jan-2024
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
"

My application.properties looks like

```
##ssl-certification 
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:amr.p12
server.ssl.key-alias=embel
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12


## Disable HTTP and force HTTPS
server.http2.enabled=false
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

Comment: 'embel' is a cert entry, not a key entry - as the error message says.  Server-side SSL requires a key entry.  How was the keystore made?

Comment: Is there any Standard documentation to do it

Comment: Since you have a cert, where did you get it?

Comment: From the site from where I bought the certificate

Comment: OK, so it's not self-signed, which puts it somewhat outside of my expertise.  Generally, you need to end up with a java keystore file containing a PrivateKeyEntry element (as shown by keytool -list).